# Regulating IPC between two processes with mutex

Tags: c++, process, synchronization, ipc

I am working on a project that creates two processes and I want to regulate the IPC between them.

The processes are created with the `createProces` function, and I want to use a mutex to do some IPC.

In Linux I do this with semaphores, however I have read that for IPC in Windows I have to use a mutex.

In windows I can't seem to get it to work. First I create the treads like this:

```
CreateProcess(IpApplicationName, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,   CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL,     &StartInfo, &ProcessInfo);
CreateProcess(IpApplicationName, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,   CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL,     &StartInfo2, &ProcessInfo2);
```

The processes start up normal but when I remove the `releaseMutex` call from one process it won't be kept waiting in that process. Here is process one:

```
volatile HANDLE hMutex; // Global hMutex Object


int main()
{
     hMutex=CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,NULL);

    while(1)
    {

        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);
        printf("Thread writing to database...\n");
        Sleep(2000);
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

In process two I open the mutex with open mutex and comment the `releaseMutex` (so that it will be stuck here, for testing. However it will keep on going):

```
int main()
{

 while(1)
 {
    HANDLE hMutex;

    hMutex=OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,MUTEXNAME);

    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);
    printf("Thread writing to database22...\n");
    Sleep(2000);
    //ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
 }

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: FYI - Windows has semaphores (CreateSemaphore) as well, although if all you need is a lock a Mutex is better as it detects dead mutex holders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create anonymous Mutex using CreateMutex, then try to find it by name

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, so i create a mutex with proces 1 and find it with proces 2? How do i find it, do you have a example?

Comment: both CreateMutex and OpenMutex have a parameter `LPCTSTR lpName`, you dont use it CreateMutex and I dont know what value MUTEXNAME is in your OpenMutex

Answer (score 4):

If you were checking errors on these Win32 API calls it would be obvious.  The `OpenMutex` call must be failing, as this code is written, since nobody else has yet created a mutex with that name.

From the [OpenMutex docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684315%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> The OpenMutex function enables multiple processes to open handles of
>   the same mutex object. **The function succeeds only if some process has
>   already created the mutex by using the CreateMutex function.**

Every Win32 API can fail - you need to check for and handle those errors properly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I checked for errors on my WINAPI calls and the open call failed indeed. And i forgot to give the mutex name in the mutexCreate call.

Comment: Good news - it will save a lot of pain if you get in the habit of checking all those API calls, and failing gracefully with suitable error output

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention `UNIQUE` mutex name both process in CreateMutex and in OpenMutex .